# In which universe did the final Doctor Strange 2 confrontation happen?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

During the final battle of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*

> America sends Wanda to another universe, where she meets another version of herself, and her children.

I had assumed this place was

> Universe 838

and therefore this character was

> the same Wanda she used for dreamwalking earlier.

But thinking back, I don't remember any character explicitly saying this. Is there any evidence (in-universe or out) that this is the same universe we saw earlier?

Comment: The Wanda sure _looks_ like the 838 one!

Comment: Not confident in this memory so not posting an answer, but I thought mom-Wanda was injured before Scarlet Witch arrived, indicating she was the same one who had been in the earlier fight.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When 616-Wanda stopped dreamwalking in 838-Wanda's body for the second time -- during the scene in the [Gap Junction](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gap_Junction), where the Book of Vishanti was located -- you could see cuts and bruises on 838-Wanda's face. She also appeared to be limping while chasing Strange, Christine, and America on foot shortly before that, so she apparently sustained some minor injuries while fighting the Illuminati and their Ultron Sentries.

The Wanda who was the mother of Billy and Tommy in that unnamed universe shown near the end of the film also had cuts and bruises on her face, corresponding to the ones 838-Wanda had. Either that's one heck of a coincidence, or it was 838-Wanda, who'd naturally be found on Earth-838.

[image]

Also, after being released from possession in the Gap Junction, 838-Wanda expressed concerned for her boys, and was implied to be rushing home to them. Showing that would serve no purpose to the plot, unless it was setting up the fact that she'd have made it home and had enough time to clean herself up and change clothes before 616-Wanda was transported there by America.

Comment: +1 Very good. Also, returning to this Universe and Wanda's sons fits best with America's plan to "Give Wanda what she wants" as she has already met the boys and covets their love.

Comment: This seems fairly convincing. I must have picked up on this subconsciously, but then couldn't remember the details after I left!

Answer (score 2):

According to the official MCU timeline, the final confrontation took place in **Universe-838**, where 616-Wanda met 838-Wanda and her children.

Here are excerpts from the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)* that confirm this (emphasis mine):

[image: page of the official timeline quoted below]

> When The Scarlet Witch gains the upper hand, Wong tells Strange to drain America's power—"It's the only way." That's what Doctor Stranges always do—they sacrifice others for what they think is best. But this universe's Strange defies expectations. Instead of taking her power, he inspires America to face her weakness: her lack of confidence. He urges her to trust her own abilities, to focus her intent, and use her skills in a way that feels right and good. **Chavez concentrates like never before and opens a gateway—directly to Bobby and Billy in their living room in Universe-838.**

> **Wanda of 838 comforts The Scarlet Witch of 616**, assuring her the boys are loved.

> The Scarlet Witch is finally stopped by what she loves: her children, who are safe and happy with their own mother, but are terrified of this sinister version of her. "l would never hurt you. I would never hurt anyone," The Scarlet Witch says, before realizing that's no longer true. **As the kindly 838-Wanda gathers the boys and assures the heartbroken Scarlet Witch they will be loved**, the Wanda Maximoff of Universe-616 surrenders. She destroys Wundagore—and collapses it upon herself—ending two great threats to all of the Multiverse.